# How can I connect to RFID Reader having LAN cable from server in C#?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, ethernet, rfid

I want to read **RF Tag** id from **RFID reader** which has LAN cable. How can I set up the C# program which can read data from RFID reader having LAN cable?
Basically How to set up the IP address of RFID reader in C# program so it can pass data to the connected server.

I had already tried connecting to RFID USB reader using serial port communication by setting up PORT number.

I'm expecting that all data from RFID reader send to its connected server over LAN cable.

Comment: The cable either needs to be a cross over cable or you need to go through a hub so the TX wires on device go to the PC RX wires and the Rx wires on device go to the PC TX wires.  The IP address of the machine also need to be in the same subnet as PC.  So from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/ALL and check IP and mask in results.

Comment: To check if the device is properly connected do ping cmd.exe >PING IP

Answer (score 3):

Most products will provide an interface specification, to explain what protocol it uses over Ethernet. Your product may provide a tiny web site accessed over http, or it may require TCP or UDP messaging to/from specific ports. Some products will provide Windows device drivers which simplify the interface effort, by making the device access look like a file access (for example). You need to start with the manufacturer documentation, which with any luck will provide sample code or example applications.